# External display is connected, but the monitor says "No Video Signal."

Tags: multiple-monitors, video, display, hdmi

I have a Toshiba TV I use as a monitor occasionally for my laptop, and recently it stopped working. The TV has connected fine in the past, and all my other monitors still connect without issue. Also I hadn't changed anything in Ubuntu before it stopped working. When I plug in the HDMI it shows in the [Display Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GfHq.png), but the TV says "No Video Signal.". Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the TV set to the HDMI input? Have you unplugged and replugged the HDMI cable at both ends?

Comment: @heynnema Yes, the input is correct and I have tried unplugging and replugging the HDMI at both ends. Did you see my picture? Could Ubuntu see the TV if there was something wrong like that?

Comment: Have you rebooted the computer with the TV turned on? I'm asking simple questions now, as you'd be surprised how some folks can miss the most obvious things.

Comment: Yes, I did try that. One weird thing did happen once while I was troubleshooting; while the TV was connected and I restarted Ubuntu, for a brief second the logoff display showed on the TV. But, I haven't been able to make it happen again. I understand that often times issues have simple answers, but I think it is something low-level. Maybe a driver? I just don't know enough about it.

Comment: To eliminate a software problem on your installation, boot to a Ubuntu Live 17.04 DVD/USB, and see if it works then. Make sure that it's 17.04. What version are you running now? Report back.

Comment: Ok, I booted up a Ubuntu Live 17.04 USB. Same problem, in the Display settings it sees the TV and says its on but the TV says "No Video Signal.". Also, my computer has the 16.04 LTS version.

Comment: Try running a DVD player, or similar, into that HDMI port on the TV and lets check that it works that way.

Comment: Yes, the TV works fine with other things. Maybe I could configure the output manually using the terminal?

Comment: You tested a DVD, or some other HDMI video source, into that SAME HDMI port that the computer was using?

Comment: Yes, I tested a Blue-ray player into the exact same HDMI input I used on the computer and there were no issues.

Comment: Hey, it works now! I played around with 'xrandr' and not sure what I did actually fixed it, but I think the command "xrandr --auto" might have done it. The resolution is a little off, but it works now.

Comment: Good job! Type `man xrandr` to find out how to set the proper display resolution for your TV.

Comment: Ok, I think I know the problem now... The cable I use has a loose wire in it. If the cable is in a certain position it works. But, if I move it, it looses signal. Not sure how the computer can still see the TV as connected if the signal isn't going through though. Thanks for the help! Yep, playing with "man xrandr" now!

Comment: Good find! If you look at my very first comment, it goes to exactly that... a bad cable/connection. I put together a VERY brief answer which we can close the question with. Please remember to vote/accept it if all our troubleshooting was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, that was embarrassingly simple! Thank you for your help and patience! And yes I voted, but its not shown yet since I'm a new member. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I got it now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

After lengthy troubleshooting, it was found to be an intermittent HDMI cable.